# Dagger Hilt won't inject a dependency in a HiltWorker

Tags: kotlin, android-studio, dagger-hilt, android-workmanager

"So, I'm trying to run some repeatable work, and I need to have access to a class and its function. **When I add private val mainRepository: MainRepository in the constructor of the @HiltWorker, I get the status of the worker as FAILED** (which is unheard of for a repeatable work). But when I remove this injection, everything works as expected. I would appreciate any help because I've been struggling with this problem quite a lot.

Here is the code of the worker:

```
   @HiltWorker
    class CustomWorker @AssistedInject constructor(
        @Assisted context: Context,
        @Assisted workerParameters: WorkerParameters,
        private val mainRepository: MainRepository
    ) : CoroutineWorker(context, workerParameters){
    
        override suspend fun doWork(): Result  {
    
        mainRepository.createLogs()
    
        return Result.success()
    
        }
    }
```

The worker is run in a composable function with LaunchedEffect:

```
  val lifecycleOwner = LocalLifecycleOwner.current

    LaunchedEffect(key1 = Unit ) {
      
        val workRequest = PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder<CustomWorker>(
            repeatInterval = 15,
            repeatIntervalTimeUnit = TimeUnit.MINUTES,
        )
            .setBackoffCriteria(
                backoffPolicy = BackoffPolicy.LINEAR,
                duration = Duration.ofMinutes(15)
            )
            .build()

        val workManager = WorkManager.getInstance(applicationContextVal)
        workManager.enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(
            "WorkerNo1",
            ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.CANCEL_AND_REENQUEUE,
            workRequest
        )


        workManager.getWorkInfosForUniqueWorkLiveData("WorkerNo1")
            .observe(lifecycleOwner){  workInfoList ->
                workInfoList.forEach {workInfo ->
                    Log.d("WorkerNo1Obs", "${workInfo.state}")
                }
            }
    }
```

The MainRepository class is:

```
  class MainRepository() {
       fun createLogs(){
        Log.d("WorkerNo1", " MainRepository: mainrepository is called")
       }
   }
```

And the Hilt moodule looks like this:

```
  @InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
    @Module
    object HiltModules {
        @Provides
        fun provideRepository(): MainRepository = MainRepository()
    }
```

The error I get in the logcat is:

```
Could not instantiate com.example.runarepeatableworkusingworkmanager.CustomWorker
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.example.runarepeatableworkusingworkmanager.CustomWorker.<init> [class android.content.Context, class androidx.work.WorkerParameters]
     at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3325)
     at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:3063)
     at androidx.work.WorkerFactory.createWorkerWithDefaultFallback(WorkerFactory.java:95)
     at androidx.work.impl.WorkerWrapper.runWorker(WorkerWrapper.java:243)
     at androidx.work.impl.WorkerWrapper.run(WorkerWrapper.java:145)
     at androidx.work.impl.utils.SerialExecutorImpl$Task.run(SerialExecutorImpl.java:96)
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:644)
     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
2023-10-03 18:24:47.868 14541-14595 WM-WorkerWrapper        com...epeatableworkusingworkmanager  E  Could not create Worker com.example.runarepeatableworkusingworkmanager.CustomWorker
```

**I need to stress that without the injection: private val mainRepository: MainRepository, the log looks normal: `ENQUEUED -> RUNNING`.** But when I add the injection, it looks like: `ENQUEUED -> FAILED`. And as you know, there is no FAILED state for a repeatable work.

If there is anyone interested in other details in the manifest file I added:

```
 <provider
            android:name="androidx.startup.InitializationProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.androidx-startup"
            android:exported="false"
            tools:node="merge"
            >
            <meta-data
                android:name="androidx.work.impl.WorkManagerInitializer"
                android:value="androidx.startup"
                tools:node="remove" />
   </provider>
```

HiltAndroidApp looks like this:

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class AppInstance : Application(), Configuration.Provider{
    @Inject lateinit var workerFactory: HiltWorkerFactory

    override fun getWorkManagerConfiguration() =
        Configuration.Builder()
            .setWorkerFactory(workerFactory)
            .build()
}
```

The app-level gradle dependencies for this problem are:

```
 implementation ("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.47")
 kapt("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.47")
 implementation ("androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.1.0-alpha01")
 implementation("androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.8.1")
 implementation("androidx.hilt:hilt-work:1.0.0")
 kapt("androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0")
```